# Take a screenshot without the UI elements in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to capture what the camera sees in phone in an AR app and take a photo of it. What I found was to take a screenshot of the device and then save that as an image. However, I want to take a screenshot of what the camera sees instead of the screen. That is without any 2D or 3D elements created in the application. Just purely what the camera sees. How do I do this?

```
public void Start() {
        StartCoroutine ("SaveImage");
}

WaitForEndOfFrame frameEnd = new WaitForEndOfFrame ();

    IEnumerator SaveImage() {
        // Create a texture the size of the screen, RGB24 format
        int width = Screen.width;
        int height = Screen.height;
        yield return frameEnd;
        var tex = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

        // Read screen contents into the texture
        tex.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
        tex.Apply ();

        byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG ();
        Destroy (tex);
        var form = new WWWForm ();
        form.AddField ("plant", plantComponentID);
        form.AddBinaryData ("image", bytes, "screenShot.png", "image/png");

        yield return null;
    }
```

Comment: Well as far as I can tell currently you do the excat opposide ... you only take into account what Unity renders not any input camera ....

Comment: @derHugo so should I disable any active UI elements in the scene while taking a screenshot?

Comment: no ... what I am saying is there is nowhere a video stream input of the actual hardware camera ... you are only storing whatever is rendered inside Unity (2D/3D content) .. see the duplicate link which provides a full solution for storing the actual hardware Camera picture

Comment: @derHugo ah okay thanks i shall check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

What I would try is to set up a [RenderTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html), and tell a camera in your scene to render to it. Then I would try to use the
[ImageConversion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.html) class to get my camera eye screenshot to a file.

This is just what my attempt would be. Not sure if that is the correct way, so providing that just in case it helps. I would be glad to know the outcome of your attempt in case you try it :)

Comment: Thanks I shall try this and see if it works :)

Comment: This will still not store any image data of the actual hardware camera .. only whatever is rendered by Unity - which what OP states is **not** supposed to end up in the image ;)

Comment: I understood it was the screenshot of the unity's camera...thanks